# How do i make the Raspberry Pi use a Custom OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, cosmos

I have made an OS is cosmos, but I cant seem to get the Raspberry Pi to actually boot the OS up. I made a bootable SD card and USB stick but the raspberry pi doesn't load anything up.

Comment: offtopic because this does not concern programming. Should be posted on [raspberry stackexchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos os only supports the x86 processor type. All versions of the raspberry pi either use ARM_6 or ARM_7. A completely different type. So what I'm saying is Cosmos OS won't work on your raspberry pi because it was made for computers with a different type of computer chip. For your raspberry pi I suggest you use raspian which is the operating system the Raspberry Pi Foundation suggests using. You can download it [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/).

Comment: Although this is a valid answer for the question, it should have been left as a comment, as the question itself is off topic.